# Is there a way to set the height of sections of a Single Page web site to 100%?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to set the height of sections of a Single Page web site to 100%.

The page I am working on has four sections, I want to put a grid of 8 boxes in the second section and I want to resize the boxes responsively.

Comment: Yes, there is a way - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a google search for height 100% tutorial dude, anyway that link may help you out http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/